# SQL Server - Counting records with same value across all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm at a complete loss on how to do this. I've been racking my brain and scouring the internet but I don't think there's any "simple" solution.

I want to be able to count occurrences for a given userID when there is the same value across multiple columns. Not all columns will have a record, but any record where all columns that aren't null that have the same value will be what I want captured in the count. I've provided an example below.

Note: I would be able to run this in either SQL Server or Access.

```
Current Table:
CREATE TABLE INFO_TABLE 
    ([UID] int, [Question1] int, [Question2] int, [Question3] int, [Question4] int, [Question5] int)
;


INSERT INTO INFO_TABLE 
    ([UID], [Question1], [Question2], [Question3], [Question4], [Question5])
VALUES
    (100, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
    (100, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5),
    (100, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5),
    (200, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
    (200, , 1, 1, 1, 1),
    (100, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
    (300, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    (400, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5),
    (400, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5),
    (300, 5, 5, 5, 5, );
```

Desired Results:

```
CREATE TABLE INFO_TABLE 
    ([UID] int, [CountFlat] int)


INSERT INTO INFO_TABLE 
    ([UID], [CountFlat])
VALUES
    (100, 2),
    (200, 2),
    (300, 2),
    (400, 0);
```

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or MS Access?  Those are very different databases.

Comment: Either would work. I tried to add both as tags and it didn't like that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select id, count(*)
from info_table
where coalesce(question1, question2, question3, question4, question5) = coalesce(question2, question3, question4, question5, question1) and
      coalesce(question1, question2, question3, question4, question5) = coalesce(question3, question4, question5, question1, question2) and
      coalesce(question1, question2, question3, question4, question5) = coalesce(question4, question5, question1, question2, question3) and
      coalesce(question1, question2, question3, question4, question5) = coalesce(question5, question1, question2, question3, question4)
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with coalesce, I'll read about that. So, my example was a condensed version of what I'd actually be doing. It will likely involve 20 some questions and many thousands of records. Do you think this would still be viable?

Comment: @user3150260 . . . You would find this much easier if you didn't store similar values in columns, but put them in rows instead.  But yes, you can extend this to more columns just by adding one more condition for each row.

Answer (score 0):

**If you normalize your data first,**

```
create table INFOTABLE_normalized
  ([UID] int, [QUESTION_SET_ID] int, [QUESTION_NUM] int, [QUESTION] int)
```

**Then the query becomes a nearly word-by-word restatement of your original question:**

```
with sets_with_only_one_distinct_question AS (
  select
    [UID]
   ,[QUESTION_SET_ID]
  from INFOTABLE_normalized
  where [QUESTION] is not NULL
  group by [UID],[QUESTION_SET_ID]
  having COUNT(DISTINCT [QUESTION]) = 1
)
select 
  [UID]
 ,COUNT([QUESTION_SET_ID]) AS [COUNT_FLAT]
from sets_with_only_one_distinct_question
group by [UID]
```